# JPanel Wont Revalidate

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel subclass called BigPanel as a content pane of a JFrame, There is a nested JPanel subclass within the BigPanel object. On a button click, the nested panel should change from one JPanel subclass to the other. The nested panel is not reseting, the correct subclass will print out to the console, but the actual panel doesn't update
    package com.grantbroadwater;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BigPanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final int DIM = GUIFrame.DIM;
private JPanel pnl1;

public BigPanel() {
    super(null);
    setSize(new Dimension(DIM, DIM));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Big Panel");
    lbl.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
    add(lbl);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Change");
    btn.setBounds(140, 20, 100, 20);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(pnl1 instanceof SubPanelOne){
                update(new SubPanelTwo());
            }else if(pnl1 instanceof SubPanelTwo){
                update(new SubPanelOne());
            }
        }

    });
    add(btn);

    pnl1 = new SubPanelOne();
    pnl1.setLocation(20, 100);
    add(pnl1);

}

private void update(JPanel pnl){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("Pnl1 is of type "+pnl1.getClass());

            pnl1 = pnl;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            pnl1.revalidate();
            pnl1.repaint();

            System.out.println(" changing to " + pnl1.getClass());
        }

    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify
2. Use a `CardLayout` to achieve what is you are trying to do, it's what it is designed for.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

The core problem seems to be lack of understanding over how variable referencing works...

```
pnl1 = pnl;
revalidate();
repaint();
pnl1.revalidate();
pnl1.repaint();
```

All this will do is change what `pnl1` was pointing to in memory to what `pnl` is pointing to in memory.  It won't affect anything on the screen.  You would physically have to remove `pnl1` and add `pnl` in order for any change to occur at all.

This increases in complexity with the discarding of the layout manager, as you would then need to update the size and position of each component each time you tried to switch them.

`invalidate`, `revalidate` and `validate` are all related to the layout management API.  They really have little meaning if you're going to choose to ignore it.